# Why includes() behaves this way in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
console.log(a.includes(4 || 5); //this yields true
console.log(a.includes(5 || 4); //this yields false
```

Why does the function includes() behave in this particular way?

Answer (score 1):

`includes` only takes one value. You may think you're telling it to check for two things, but you're not. The `||` operator is going to compare the two operands and resolve to a single value. If the left hand side of the `||` is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) then that will be used.

In short: `4 || 5` is no different from just `4`, and `5 || 4` is no different from just `5`. So your first line checks if `a` includes `4`, and the second checks if it includes `5`.

If you need to check multiple values, either call includes multiple times, or use a different method like `.find`

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4];
const element = a.find(val => val === 4 || val === 5);
const found = !!element; // turning it into true/false instead of 4/5/undefined
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

> a=[1,2,3,4]
>
> console.log(a.includes(4 || 5)); //this yields true

`4 || 5` will be executed first. The Result is `4`

`4` is included in `a` and the Result is `true`

> console.log(a.includes(5 || 4)); //this yields false

`5 || 4` results in `5`

`5` is not included in `a` and the Result is `false`

The function `includes()` behaves as it should.

---

I guess the confusion comes from this part:

```
4 || 5 = 4

5 || 4 = 5
```

For Example: **X || Y**

If X is undefined, the result will be Y

If X is defined the result will be X

In both of your examples the **"X"** is defined with a Number. The result is as expected the fist Number.

---

I hope that was helpful :)